# The way to reduce out rate on an network interface to 0

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've got a Windows 10 machine.
I need to reduce the "Out speed" on one of my network interfaces to 0 KB/s.
How can I do that? Without disabling that interface.

I tried to create rules in Windows Defender Firewall, but it affects all my network interfaces and the "Out speed" wasn't 0 KB/s.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do if you are not disabling the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can install one of these tools to limit your network connection speed from Windows:

1. [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/)
2. [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/)